# AWS SAM - Test lambda was invoked, test kinesis event was created

Tags: javascript, testing, aws-lambda, amazon-kinesis, aws-sam

I'm investigating whether AWS SAM can be used within the context of an application I'm working on.

Basically the structure of the application is that you have things like:

```
[kinesis event] -> [my lambda] -> [invokes another lambda]
```

or

```
[kinesis event] -> [my lambda] -> [creates a different kinesis event]
```

or

```
[another lambda] => [invokes my lambda] => [invokes yet another lambda]
```

So what I want to be able to is write some tests like:

```
Given that I invoke myLambda with data ABC,
 then I expect otherLambda to have been invoked with DEF.
```

or

```
Given that I put event ABC on the kinesis stream,
 then I expect that myLamdba was executed,
 and I expect that it put event DEF on the kinesis stream
```

While I can [see all of the functionality for invoking lambdas locally,](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/serverless-application-model/latest/developerguide/serverless-sam-cli-using-invoke.html) I can't see any functionality about making assertions against other lambdas being called etc.

Is this out of scope of what AWS SAM does?

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this will help but here's my two pence on the problem. Feel free to let me know if I completely missunderstood your question!

AWS SAM is only there to help you get your application into AWS, sure it will make local testing a bit easier / harder on some contexts but the idea is the same.

Consider that while you are working with 2+ lambdas invoking each other, they should be functions in the end so you'd argue they need to be independently testable. How I see it, you have a couple of options you can consider:

- You put a queue between lambdas so that when you have a Kinesis event firing Lambda A doing some processing, then it can put a message and trigger Lambda B with the processed data.
- You could explore the use of [step functions](https://aws.amazon.com/step-functions/features/) and see if it fits your particular case.
- Or finally your middle case on the question actually works, if you look on the [event sources listed for Lambdas](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/serverless-application-model/latest/developerguide/sam-property-function-eventsource.html) you can use Kinesis and then just fire another Kinesis event there if you will. (*Depending on your use case this might be a better solution than queues*)

***TL;DR: Sam will do anything others already do, it's a matter of organising your functions and making sure they are not dependant on each other.***